# retrieve data from post requests in the form of JSON structure

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-app-engine

I am working on app engine in python, with a handler to response the post requests from javascript, the post requests are sent in JSON structure, in firebug console window, the Http request is shown:

```
[{"name":"John","value":"student"},{"name":"Mike","value":"teacher"}]
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this JSON data off the post requests in the handler?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import json

class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        # Convert JSON from the request to Python objects.
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)

        # For your sample input, data will be a list of dicts.
        for person in data:
            name = person['name']
            value = person['value']
```

Comment: This will enable you to process the Jason as a dictionary.

Comment: Not necessarily. The OP's example data is a list so `data` in my code will be a Python list. JSON doesn't require you to use dicts.

Comment: It's a list of dicts. Wasn't negating your point but clarifying to the asker :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then. I extended the code to show what `data` is.

Comment: Cool. Btw just noticed iPad autocomplete fixed my json to jason :)

Comment: Thank you yah that exactly answers my question, and thank you David for your comments as well.